# How can I separate these two outputs using awk command

Tags: text-processing, awk

Here's my output:

```
MessageID=3990592283244651750-30192b51.13df831d93a.7eb4;EsbTiming=2013-04-12T01:07:46.099
```

I want only the time.

How can I separate them?

Comment: So output Should be `07:46.099` ?

Answer (score 3):

Analyse the structure of the input:

```
key1=value1;key2=value2
```

These are fields separated by `;`, which you can parse by making `;` the field separator. Then, to extract the value of a field, use the `sub` function to remove the `key=` part (or `split` on `/=/` and take the second part, or take the substring after the `index` of `=`). If the time is always in the second field, this is a simple approach:

```
awk -F ';' '{sub(/^[^=]*=/, $2); print $2}'
```

If you want to access the field by name (which is probably more robust), you can loop over the fields:

```
awk -F ';' '{i=1; while (i <= NF) {if ($i ~ /^EsbTiming=/) {sub(/^[^=]*=/, $i); print $i}}}'
```

If you only have one line to parse, it's simpler to make `;` the record separator and `=` the field separator.

```
awk -F '=' -v RS=';' '$1 == "EsbTiming" {print $2}'
```

Note that this prints an extra newline. This isn't a concern if you're using this command in a command substitution in a shell script `(… | awk …)`. If you don't want this extra newline, set `ORS` (output record separator) to the empty string:

```
awk -F '=' -v RS=';' -v ORS= '$1 == "EsbTiming" {print $2}'
```

There's also the direct regular expression approach, which here gives good results.

```
awk 'match($0, /(^|;)EsbTiming=/) {s = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH); sub(/;.*/, "", s); print s}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several awk answers, here's one way you could do it with bash. First evaluate the variable setting:

```
source <(echo "MessageID=3990592283244651750-30192b51.13df831d93a.7eb4;EsbTiming=2013-04-12T01:07:46.099")
```

You can now access `EsbTiming` directly, e.g.:

```
printf "Date: %s\nTime: %s\n" ${EsbTiming%T*} ${EsbTiming#*T}
```

Output:

```
Date: 2013-04-12
Time: 01:07:46.099
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=":" } /Timing/ {print $2":"$3 }' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk  '/Timing/{split($0,arr,":") } {print arr[2]":"arr[3]}'  input_file
```

OR

```
awk -F: '/Timing/{$1=""; print}'  input_file
```

Grep Solution

```
grep -oP '(?<=EsbTiming=.{14}).*' Input_file
```

Comment: This get's rid of the colons, ":". I'm getting this " 07 46.099".

Comment: @slm I have updated one more ans

Answer (score 1):

Simple, split by "T"

```
awk -F 'T' {'print $3'} input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

A grep solution:

```
grep -oP "(?<=EsbTiming=).*" input
```

`-o` to print only the match, not whole line

`-P` to use Perl regex, so we can use...

`(?<=lookahead_expr)` will return a match for the regex following is "positive lookbehind" -- in our case, returning the time string that follows the string 'EsbTiming='

Comment: He asked for `awk` based solution

Comment: I'm aware. He should use the right tool for the job. Granted I don't know his specific circumstances, but based on the question, grep is a simpler choice.

Comment: `-P` uses Perl regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `awk` and `sed` here's a pretty straightforward way to do it:

```
sed 's/.*Timing=//' file.txt |awk -FT '{print $2}'
```

`sed` portion collapses everything up to and including the string "Timing=" out leaving you with:

```
2013-04-12T01:07:46.099
```

`awk` splits on the character "T" and we print out the 2nd field which is your time.

```
01:07:46.099
```